# @RetryTopic configuration impacts application performance

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

`Spring Boot` `v2.6.7` application which is already available on production that consumes data from `Kafka`, does transformation and stores data to database.

To process 100k `Kafka` records application requires approx. 10 minutes on my local machine (where local `Kafka` in `docker`, topic with one partition and one single consumer enabled):

```
first run: 10 min 20 sec. 
second run: 10 min 05 sec. 
third run: 10 min 36 sec.
```

That I decided to introduce non-blocking error handling and add a few beans:

```
   @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> retryProducerKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getSecurity().getProtocol());

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration() {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .maxAttempts(2)
                .retryTopicSuffix("-retry")
                .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
                .dltSuffix("-dlt")
                .includeTopics(consumerTopics)
                .exponentialBackoff(1000, 2, 10000)
                .retryOn(List.of(DataAccessException.class))
                .dltHandlerMethod("eventsListener", "dlt")
                .create(retryProducerKafkaTemplate());
    }
```

all what I literally did  - it just added these 3 beans, **no** other configuration affected.

Run new batch of 100k tests and got the following results:

```
first run: 11min 20sec
second run:11min 12sec
third run: 11min 30sec
```

Seems like adding non-blocking error handling for `Kafka` immediately degrades the performance ~10%, that surprise me a lot.

Does anyone else meet the same situation? and also got a negative impact on app performance?
Or potentially I just miss something in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You've not just added that beans but have enabled the *exponential backoff*.

In the default configuration the retry behavior is managed by [DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters) which is executed in the same consumer thread. The latency is caused by `Fetcher#getTopicMetadata` that sends the poll request to broker and may take about ~100ms\exception.

See the profiler sample. In my case, it spent about ~60% of total time for this purpose:

[image]

I'm not sure if there's much to do. I would suggest to use more partitions for your topic and setup the concurrency.

When not specifying the retry policy the error handling is delegated to `DefaultBackOffHandler` and the current consumer thread is paused to process all the tries before it is resumed bypassing the interaction with the broker.

Comment: I have just sent to Kafka 2 messages: first one that leads to DataAccessException and the second one that is absolutely valid.

as result, application successfully processed both messages, first one was moved to retry topic, the second one successfully stored in DB, so I can't confirm your statement that entire consumption was blocked.

Comment: Yep, you're partially right. Please see the update